# CheckAccessCore not being called in custom ServiceAuthorizationManager

Tags: wcf, rest, azure

I am working on a WCF REST service that will be hosted within Azure and want to check the user id. To this end I have created a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager.

```
namespace SecureService
{
    public class AccessControlServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager 
    {
        String serviceNamespace      = String.Empty;
        String acsHostname           = String.Empty;
        String trustedTokenPolicyKey = String.Empty;
        String trustedAudience       = String.Empty;

        public AccessControlServiceAuthorizationManager()
        {
            try
            {
                serviceNamespace      = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("serviceNamespace");
                acsHostname           = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("acsHostname");
                trustedTokenPolicyKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("trustedTokenPolicyKey");
                trustedAudience       = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("trustedAudience");
            }
            catch
            {
                GenerateErrorResponse();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }                                   // end AccessControlServiceAuthorizationManager() Constructor

        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            String headerValue = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
            String token = String.Empty;
            string[] nameValuePair = null;
            TokenValidator validator = null;


            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
            {
                GenerateErrorResponse();
                return false;
            }

            if (!headerValue.StartsWith("WRAP "))
            {
                GenerateErrorResponse();
                return false;
            }

            nameValuePair = headerValue.Substring("WRAP ".Length).Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);

            if (nameValuePair.Length != 2 || 
                nameValuePair[0] != "access_token" || 
                !nameValuePair[1].StartsWith("\"") || 
                !nameValuePair[1].EndsWith("\""))
            {
                GenerateErrorResponse();
                return false;
            }

            token     = nameValuePair[1].Substring(1, nameValuePair[1].Length - 2);
            validator = new TokenValidator(acsHostname, serviceNamespace, trustedAudience, trustedTokenPolicyKey);

            if (!validator.Validate(token))
            {
                GenerateErrorResponse();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void GenerateErrorResponse()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Web.config is as follows;

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Secure">
                <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="SecureService.AccessControlServiceAuthorizationManager" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">                       
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="SecureService.Demo">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SecureService.IDemo" />
            <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SecureService.IDemo" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

However the CheckAccessCore() method does not seem to be called when I call the service via IE. So the question is how can I ensure it is called and therefore ensure that my users are validated.

I have put a break point in the CheckAccessCore and it never seems to get hit.

And just to make things really interesting - I will need to call this webservice from within Silverlight.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following the configuration pasted above, I see that service behavior "Secure" is missed to apply on Service. Please check it, if it's not a typo...

Comment: Nope - not a typo. I could not figure out a way to add it to the service tag - what should I put in there.

Comment: You can add behaviorConfiguration="Secure" in <service> element i.e. after adding behaviorConfiguration, service element should look as below,
<service name="SecureService.Demo" behaviorConfiguration="Secure">

Answer (score 0):

Ignore your 'services' section in config. Try:

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="True" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="True"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```